# How to redirect a user logged in with the Spatie-permission package using Laravel UI?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have already configured with permissions the menu that starts and accesses the user, the problem is when I log in, it automatically redirects me to the home page, which is something I want that not all users have access to the home page, but for example a salesman who redirects him to the home page automatically exits.

I've read examples on the internet that create middleware but I don't know how they work, then if you have to invoke it in the paths.

The login I am using is the default one with Laravel

Comment: Which Laravel auth mechanism are you using?

Comment: I'm taking the default with Laravel, no custom login. @Unflux

Comment: Take a look at [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tafzPLRP92I) which covers  your use case.

Answer (score 1):

use AuthenticatesUsers;

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user){
    if($user->hasRole('SuperAdmin')){
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('Admin')){
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('Management')){
        return redirect('/managment_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('FrontDesk')){
        return redirect('/fdo_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('DataEntry')){
        return redirect('/data_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('SalesMarketing')){
        return redirect('/sales_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('Accounts')){
        return redirect('/accounts_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('Dealer')){
        return redirect('/dealer_panel');
    }
    elseif($user->hasRole('Member')){
        return redirect('/user_panel');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a good practice to advocate your solution